# SQLite Java JDBC Insert

Tags: java, jdbc

Following is my Java code. In linux, it is working fine but in Windows I'm unable to insert data into the database on local disk. In NetBeans get it all right but `.jar` file not. JDBC driver see be good.

Connecting to database:

```
public static Connection connectToDb() {
    try {
        Connection connection = null;
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
        //LINUX PATH
        if (OSDetector.isLinux()) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/" + userNameLinux + "/PDFMalwareDataAnalyser/DatabaseSQLite/database.db", NAME, PASSWORD);
            //WINDOWS PATH 
        } else {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\PDFMalwareDataAnalyser\\DatabaseSQLite\\database.db", NAME, PASSWORD);
        }
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Otvorená.");
        }
        return connection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + e.getMessage());
        //  System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Insertion:

```
public void insertDataToDatabase(int idReport) throws SQLException {
    connection = new SQLiteJDBC().connectToDb();
    PreparedStatement insertCommunication = connection.prepareStatement("insert into table_communication values(?,?);");
    insertCommunication.setString(2, communicationsFinal.toString());
    try {
        insertCommunication.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    insertCommunication.close();
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("1. --- Insert do tabuľky TABLE_COMMUNICATION OK ---");
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say. Please be more clear. Also, what exception are you getting?

Comment: i want insert data to database... in netbeans i can insert but after .jar file generating data are not inserted in windows, but in linux is that okey..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/PDFMalwareDataAnalyser/DatabaseSQLite/database.db")
```

Comment: Your code is working fine
[Database Class](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/SZhUCLFD)
[Main](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/5dfEZT8j)